# Cumulative average by category

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Example]
Is there any way to get the cumulative average for cells of rows that are not grouped together?
In other words, how can I tell AVERAGE to look for other cells in the D column that are in a row that contains the same text in the A column as that of the row in which function is being used?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Your example describes one thing, and you accepted an answer that performs something different.  It's great that you got an answer that satisfies your needs, but this disparity will make this thread confusing for anyone with a related problem, and other readers may waste time trying to provide an answer that matches your example.  I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I know this is almost 10 year old, but I only just saw it.
I honestly am not sure what you mean. Perhaps the wording could be changed a bit, but the answer does exactly what I asked and that's why I marked it as correct.
The key is `how can I tell AVERAGE to look for other cells in the D column that are in a row that contains the same text in the A column as that of the row in which function is being used?`
The wording could be improved, but I'm not exactly sure what would be acceptable to you. Clearly someone understood and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642) will allow you to specify a criteria and range to average if the criteria is met.

It uses the syntax of `AVERAGEIF(range, criteria, [average_range])`

Here is a formula that should work for your sheet.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,C:C)
```

This formula will look in the range `A:A` (column A) for matches to `A2`. Then it averages the values in `C:C` (column C) and returns the result.

Create this formula for each criteria by changing the `A2` to the cell of the value you wish to average.

Comment: He needs cumulative average,  instead of whole column references use `A$2:A2` and `C$2:C2`.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks. I saw the word cumulative, but answered according to what the OP described in the body of their question. Apparently, that was what they were looking for.